# NLP - How to deal with a dataset where some spaces between words are missing

Tags: dataset, natural-language

I've been normalizing a dataset and after tokenizing my words I've noticed that some records contain combinations of words where the spaces between them are missing.

```
ie. The quickbrown fox jumped over thelazydog.
```

I was thinking about trying to work with a spell checker where if I find that the word is misspelled then I could try to figure out if there is a way to split up the string into correctly spelled words. The problem I see with this approach is with words like `microsoft`, which would be broken up into `micro` and `soft`.

How would you deal with this dirty dataset? Would you leave these combined words as part of the vocabulary, remove all misspelled words, try to split them up, or replace misspelled words with a  placeholder `The * fox jumped over *.`?

Comment: No solution will be 100% correct, but a quick way to get started is to look at all the spell checker’s proposed replacements & not make the replacements when it’s clearly wrong. Another aspect is that Microsoft to “micro soft” is also a change of case (M to m), and the *phrase* “micro soft” is much less likely to occur than the word “Microsoft.” This gives more details (case-sensitive, probability-awareness) to differentiate among the words. The best solution is to fix whatever the cause of the missing spaces is, but perhaps that’s infeasible.

Comment: Calculate the Levenshtein distances using the ' ' as an allowable character and a standard English dictionary for reference. If "Microsoft" needs to be a word, you need to include it in your dictionary. Still can't guarantee that microasoft won't be changed to "Microsoft" versus "micro soft" unless you modify weights.